# openproject installation issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, openproject

I am trying to install openproject by following this link to install into amazon centos instance:
https://www.openproject.org/download/packaged-installation-core/

But I am getting below error and it is getting failed.

```
[root@ip-10-28-11-38 ec2-user]# sudo yum install openproject
```

> Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper amzn-main/latest
>   | 2.1 kB     00:00 amzn-updates/latest
>   | 2.3 kB     00:00 openproject
>   | 2.9 kB     00:00 openproject/primary_db
>   |  50 kB     00:00 Resolving Dependencies
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package openproject.x86_64 0:4.0.6-1422376810.876f3af.centos6 will be installed
>   --> Processing Dependency: postgresql-libs for package: openproject-4.0.6-1422376810.876f3af.centos6.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: mysql-libs for package: openproject-4.0.6-1422376810.876f3af.centos6.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libevent for package: openproject-4.0.6-1422376810.876f3af.centos6.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: dialog for package: openproject-4.0.6-1422376810.876f3af.centos6.x86_64
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package dialog.x86_64 0:1.1-9.20080819.1.5.amzn1 will be installed
>   ---> Package libevent.x86_64 0:2.0.18-1.10.amzn1 will be installed
>   ---> Package mysql55-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.40-1.3.amzn1 will be installed
>   ---> Package postgresql92-libs.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1.46.amzn1 will be installed
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Dependencies Resolved
>
> ================================================================================  Package           Arch   Version                            Repository
>   Size
>   ================================================================================ Installing:  openproject       x86_64 4.0.6-1422376810.876f3af.centos6
>   openproject   56 M Installing for dependencies:  dialog
>   x86_64 1.1-9.20080819.1.5.amzn1           amzn-main    205 k  libevent
>   x86_64 2.0.18-1.10.amzn1                  amzn-main    278 k 
>   mysql55-libs      x86_64 5.5.40-1.3.amzn1
>   amzn-updates 813 k  postgresql92-libs x86_64 9.2.9-1.46.amzn1
>   amzn-main    254 k
>
> Transaction Summary
>   ================================================================================ Install  1 Package (+4 Dependent packages)
>
> Total download size: 58 M 
>   Installed size: 198 M 
>   Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
>   Downloading packages: 
>   (1/5): dialog-1.1-9.20080819.1.5.amzn1.x86_64.rpm        | 205 kB     00:00
>   (2/5): libevent-2.0.18-1.10.amzn1.x86_64.rpm             | 278 kB     00:00
>   (3/5): mysql55-libs-5.5.40-1.3.amzn1.x86_64.rpm          | 813 kB      00:00 
>   (4/5): openproject-4.0.6-1422376810.876f3af.centos6.x86_ |  56 MB     00:03 
>   (5/5): postgresql92-libs-9.2.9-1.46.amzn1.x86_64.rpm     | 254 kB     00:00
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Total                                            15 MB/s |  58 MB
>   00:03 Running transaction check 
>   Running transaction test 
>   Transaction test succeeded 
>   Running transaction   Installing :
>   dialog-1.1-9.20080819.1.5.amzn1.x86_64
>   1/5   Installing : postgresql92-libs-9.2.9-1.46.amzn1.x86_64
>   2/5   Installing : mysql55-libs-5.5.40-1.3.amzn1.x86_64
>   3/5   Installing : libevent-2.0.18-1.10.amzn1.x86_64
>   **4/5 /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.NKChbC: line 18: addgroup: command not found**
>   **error: %pre(openproject-4.0.6-1422376810.876f3af.centos6.x86_64)**
>   **scriptlet failed, exit status 127 Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm**
>   **package openproject-4.0.6-1422376810.876f3af.centos6.x86_64**
>   Verifying  : libevent-2.0.18-1.10.amzn1.x86_64
>   1/5   Verifying  : mysql55-libs-5.5.40-1.3.amzn1.x86_64
>   2/5   Verifying  : postgresql92-libs-9.2.9-1.46.amzn1.x86_64
>   3/5   Verifying  : dialog-1.1-9.20080819.1.5.amzn1.x86_64
>   4/5   Verifying  : openproject-4.0.6-1422376810.876f3af.centos6.x86_64
>   5/5
>
> Dependency Installed:   dialog.x86_64 0:1.1-9.20080819.1.5.amzn1
>   libevent.x86_64 0:2.0.18-1.10.amzn1   mysql55-libs.x86_64
>   0:5.5.40-1.3.amzn1   postgresql92-libs.x86_64 0:9.2.9-1.46.amzn1
>
> **Failed:   openproject.x86_64 0:4.0.6-1422376810.876f3af.centos6**
>
> Complete!

Can anybody help me for solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the addgroup command is not found on your system. Try if you can execute the addgroup command (e.g.: `sudo addgroup`). If it is not found try what is suggested here: [Bash: groupadd: command not found](https://superuser.com/questions/180898/bash-groupadd-command-not-found)

Comment: thanks for the reply but it is not working,
 i am thinking their is a problem with centos thing, i created new instance with ubuntu and installed openproject and everything is working fine..